# Activity indicator not hiding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to use activity indicator to show loading activity, like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //Create cell

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCellView" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    // Check condition, either we got objects

    if (!isDataLoaded){

        cell.myActivityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                        initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

        cell.myActivityIndicator.center=self.view.center;
        [cell.myActivityIndicator startAnimating];
        [self.view addSubview:cell.myActivityIndicator];

        NSLog(@"Current loading");

    }   else {

        cell.myActivityIndicator.hidden = YES;
        [cell.myActivityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

    }


    return cell;
}
```

However, its not vanish, even when i know that "else" block is executed. How to hide it?

Comment: Is there more than one row in your table view? If so, is `isDataLoaded` specific to each row? Don't forget about cell reuse. Your code can easily add multiple activity views to a cell or try to remove the activity view from the wrong cell.

Comment: @rmaddy isDataLoaded setted to YES when controller get notification about data load.